# PHP: Error using $_GET['value'] when value is not present in URL

Tags: php, get

I'm trying to display a simple confirmation message after a PHP contact form has sent an e-mail and redirected to the previous page.
I'm redirecting like so:

```
header("Location: contact.php?mailsend");
```

In the contact.php I'm trying to display the confirmation this way:

```
<?php 
  $mailsend = $_GET['mailsend'];
  if ($mailsend == 1){
      echo "<div><p>Your e-mail was sent.</p></div>";
  }
?>
```

But the page only loads properly if `mailsend` is present in the URL. When it is not, the page doesn't load (it shows my CMS' error page).

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

Wrapping my php in an isset statement, as suggested in the comments:

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_GET['mailsend'])) {
    $mailsend = $_GET['mailsend'];
    if ($mailsend == 1){
        echo "<div><p>Your e-mail was sent.</p></div>";
    }
  }
?>
```

The page no longer throws an error, but also never displays the confirmation, even if the URL is contains `mailsend=1`

Comment: You're probably getting a hidden warning about undefined index. Use `isset` to check the key exists rather than simply using it. If it is set, you can just set it to 1 since you don't expect a value. E.g. `if (isset($_GET['mailsend']))`.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks for the fast reply. I tried wrapping everything in an isset statement; now the page no longer throws an error but the confirmation also isn't displayed. See the update in the question. Any mistakes I made there?

Comment: I didn't say wrap it, I meant for you to replace it. Get rid of everything within the new `if` block aside from the `echo`.

Comment: ahhh I see, thanks :) Works just fine. You wanna put it in an official answer so I can give you an upvote?

Comment: I can't as the question has been marked as a duplicate, but it's fine as long as you're sorted.

Comment: alright, thanks again though